# ¿Qué es y de dónde proviene la palabra "inlatencia"?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, palabras-raras, significado-en-contexto, neologismos

¿Qué es y de dónde proviene la palabra "inlatencia"?

> - Neologismo que reproduce el que forma el autor y cuyo sentido sería la no-latencia (T.).

> Se trata para él de acordarse precisamente de nada, pero que
> también como nada, anticipa toda presencia y toda memoria. De hecho, si algo diferencia la tradición humana es precisamente el hecho de que quiere salvar no sólo lo insalvable (las características esenciales de la especie), sino aquello que en todo caso no puede ser salvado, que está siempre perdido, que mejor dicho, no ha sido nunca poseído como una propiedad específica, sino que es, precisamente por esto, inolvidable: el ser, la **inlatencia** del soma infantil [...]. (Agamben 1989: 78-80; énfasis mío)

> Por algún lugar dentro de nosotros el atolondrado muchacho neoténico continúa su juego real. Y es su jugar el que nos da tiempo, el que mantiene abierta esa inagotable **inlatencia** que los pueblos y las lenguas de la tierra, cada uno a su manera, procuran conservar y diferir –y conservar sólo en la medida en que la aplazan. Sólo el día en que la originaria **inlatencia** infantil fuese verdaderamente, vertiginosamente asumida como tal, el tiempo alcanzado y el muchacho Aion despertase de su juego y a su juego, entonces los hombres podrían al fin construir una historia y una lengua universales no diferibles, y detener su vagar en las tradiciones. Este auténtico revocar el soma infantil de la humanidad se llama: el pensamiento, es decir, la política (Agamben, 1989: 80).

> El contenido del experimentum es sólo que hay lenguaje y que nosotros no podemos representarlo, según el modelo que ha dominado nuestra cultura, como una lengua, un estado o un patrimonio de nombres y reglas que cada pueblo transmite de generación en generación; más bien sería la **inlatencia** imposible de presuponer que los hombres desde siempre habitan y dentro de la cual, hablando, respiran y se mueven. A pesar de los cuarenta milenios del homo sapiens, el hombre aún no ha procurado asumir esa inlatencia y hacer la experiencia de su ser hablante. (p. 221)

> Se trata, entonces, de pensar el origen no como causa sino como potencia "más allá de todo destino específico y de toda vocación genética" (1989: 79). Por ello, no resulta casual que sus indagaciones en torno a esta noción se encuentren en estrecha vinculación con una pregunta por el lenguaje (en particular por la "voz" y la "infancia"), con la constatación de que 'hay lenguaje', de que el hombre habla' aunque no lo haga siempre, aunque pueda no hacerlo (cfr. 2007: 213-222). Dicho de otro modo, es en la constatación de que hay lenguaje pero que no lo tenemos naturalmente, que hay en él una resto negativo que garantiza su potencia- de hablar y de no hacerlo-, que Agamben encuentra la hendidura, el origen-límite, la "indeterminada **inlatencia** " (1989: 79) que hace del hombre un ser histórico. Porque, tal y como afirma en Infancia e Historia (2007: 218): para un ser cuya experiencia del lenguaje no se presentara desde siempre escindida en lengua y discurso, que fuera desde siempre hablante, desde siempre en una lengua indivisible, no existiría ni conocimiento, ni infancia, ni
> historia: estaría siempre inmediatamente unido a su naturaleza lingüística y no encontraría en ninguna parte una discontinuidad y una diferencia donde algo como un saber y una historia pudiera producirse.

> La piedra del poema, que metafóricamente el poeta atinó a nombrar como madre, es simplemente piedra. Pero en su intimidad, esa zona impenetrable, guarda un corazón en la **inlatencia** de la materia. A ese centro-madre, a esa materia dura que rechaza la metáfora, es a lo que el pensamiento y el lenguaje se enfrentan desde su propia dureza ante lo simple del hay. Es así como podemos pensar la experiencia del hay ahí (lugar que es el hay de las cosas y al mismo tiempo es la cosa del pensamiento y la cosa del lenguaje), de la que no sabemos si podemos identificar siquiera como una experiencia, y que diagrama esa cinta de Moebius donde la poesía toca la cosa de las palabras y donde esa materia es rozada por la palabra.

> El artículo termina con una frase que señala las tensiones sexuales presentes en la canción: «Nada más atroz que la **inlatencia** de la tiza para un corazón al que el orgasmo curaría».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un [artículo de plantas en Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDCP9PC) que cuenta con un menú de condiciones y características de cada ejemplar. Entre estos aparece "inlatencia" como una de las opciones. En la página en inglés la misma opción es *dormancy* = inactividad.

[image: Inlatencia]

[image: dormancy]

---

El último párrafo de la pregunta que refiere a la canción de Spinetta, explica el significado en las siguientes líneas de donde es extraído, refiriendo a la "falta de latido de la tiza" ([enlace](https://teoriaenpocosminutos.wordpress.com/2020/09/25/la-carne-y-el-poder-que-carga/)), lo contrario a *latencia*.

> La tiza no siente y el rayón no late.

Según explica, la letra de la canción es por un amor no correspondido donde la joven tienen ojos de papel y corazón de tiza, ambos elementos inhertes e inexpresivos, en consecuencia inactivos, por la falta de pasión.

---

Respecto al párrafo que habla del *experimentum*, en la misma página hay una llamada con la explicación de la palabra *inlatencia* refiriéndose a la misma como un *neologismo*:

> Neologismo que reproduce el que forma el autor y cuyo sentido sería la nolatencia

De ser este el caso, *inlatencia* pasaría a formar parte del amplio listado de neologismos creados con el prefijo `in` para definir antónimos y que no aparecen en la RAE, algunos de uso bastante corriente como *incumplible*, *indiscriminación*, *incivismo* o *indagable*.

Comment: En realidad es correspondido, pero también habla de la oportunidad de una mujer ciega de ver y sentir a través de la visión estructurada y subjetiva del otro,  que le hace o "impone" mediante su propuesta. Pero, en resumen "inlatencia" es precisamente "no latencia" y no "ilatencia".

Answer (score 0):

**Inlatencia**

Cita "Neologismo que reproduce el que forma el autor y cuyo sentido sería la nolatencia".

---

**Latencia**

- 1. f. Cualidad o condición de latente.
- 2. f. Biol. Tiempo que transcurre entre un estímulo y la respuesta que produce, y, en particular, lapso entre el momento en que se contrae una enfermedad y la aparición de los primeros síntomas.

---

Al definir la RAE "**Latencia**" de la forma anterior, podríamos pensar que "**In-latencia**" tendría que ver con aquella definición, sin embargo no es así, ya que el concepto principal de la mayoría de los enunciados de la pregunta principal corresponden al campo del saber filosófico donde "**Latencia e Inlatancia**" tienen un significado distinto.

---

Por resumir un poco, la "**latencia**" en filosofía posee sentido transcendental y se manifiesta en la incapacidad de obtener una comprensión completa de las cosas. Por otra parte, la "**latencia**" hace referencia a algo que esta o se encuentra oculto.

Por contra la "**inlatencia**" hace referencia a la "αλήθεια" "alētheia", la "verdad", en su sentido etimológico procedería de "a", no ó sin y el verbo "letho", ocultar, olvidar..., "a-letheia", literalmente "sin ocultar", por tanto, la verdad es lo que no está oculto y es evidente.

De esta manera, tanto la "**inlatencia**" como "**alētheia**" son términos que hacen referencia al "desocultamiento del ser o de las cosas" lo que en filosofía se atendía por "verdad".

En los campos o ejemplos mencionados de Giorgio Agamben hay que entender la ocultación y la no ocultación (desocultamiento) del ser y las cosas. Así mientras la "**latencia**" puede referirse a la ocultación y a la inconsciencia del ser y de las cosas "ocultas", en sentido filosófico, la "**inlatencia**" haría referencia a todo lo contrario, a lo que no esta oculto, es decir, **a la verdad y a la consciencia** que podemos tener de la vida y de las cosas como parte de esa memoria biológica del ser, donde es posible recobrar ciertas imágenes que pasan de la "**latencia**" (inconsciencia) a la "**inlatencia**" (consciencia).

P.D. Para un estudio más profundo de estos temas aconsejaría el libro de Carlos Albeto Disandro (1919-1994). "Filosofía y poesía en el pensar griego".

[image]

Del libro "Filosofía y poesía en el pensar griego"

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta confunde *inlatencia* con *ilatencia* [(*Referencia*)](https://economiapoliticaehucv.wordpress.com/2020/04/25/ocultamiento-o-indeterminacion-comentarios-sobre-lo-abierto-el-hombre-y-el-animal-de-giorgio-agamben/)

Comment: Error de los editores en los libros de googlebooks. Gracias por el esfuerzo +1